# How to check if $1 contains special characters in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I want to check if `$1`  has any of the following special characters `@#$%&*-=+`

User will run the script like this:

```
testserver@matrix:~> scriptname somer@nd$m
```

script should detect if `somer@nd$m` has any special character!
Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Why are you trying to check for that? What are you concerned about there?

Comment: @EtanReisner smells an X-Y problem. So do I.

Comment: I am doing this for University assignment for introduction to bash scripting. The entire assignment is complete, but I am stuck at special characters.

Answer (score 4):

In general, to determine if a variable contains a member of a set of characters, you can use [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) with a character set as described in the bash manual.

```
[[ $var = *[set]* ]]
```

In your case, the set composition is tricky. It contains "&" and "-", which have special meaning. The dash goes first, or the shell considers the character set a *range*. The ampersand just has to be escaped. So you have to do

```
[[ $var = *[-@#$%'&'*=+]* ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for just the existence of a special characters you can use

```
if egrep -q "[@#$%&*-=+]" <<< "$1"
then
    echo "Special Characters"
fi
```

Be aware though in your example that passing in `somer@nd$m` will try to find a variable named `m` unless you pass the argument in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have tried this method and it did not work. even with single quotes around. I also tried to take the out of grep in regular expression and compare it with $1 argument, but that did not work either! Thanks

Comment: The expression is being interpreted as a character set _range_ because of the dash.